# loading javascript in laravel 4 - syntax error, unexpected 'assets' (T_STRING)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to load my javascript which is basically in this folder, f.ex. `public\assets\contract_app\load-scripts.js`

Atm I am loading the scripts like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/test_app/')}}load-scripts.js      "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/test_app/')}}script.js                "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/test_app/')}}options.js           "></script>
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "syntax error, unexpected 'assets' (T_STRING)"

Stacktrace:
#1 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-test\app\storage\views\7b9d8c08d036e7d846a7a4ea676e0658:695
#0 Illuminate\Exception\Handler:handleShutdown in <#unknown>:0
```

What am I doing wrong? How to properly load my js in laravel 4?

I appreciate your reply!

**UPDATE**

The view is called:

[image]

And I am calling it in my `route.php` with:

```
Route::get('contract', function() {
    return View::make('site/contract_v02');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried just the regular helper function `asset('assets/test_app/')`?

Comment: There's also the alternative way of generating the entire tags with `{{ HTML::script('path/to/script.js') }}` and `{{ HTML::style('path/to/stylesheet.css') }}`

Comment: Is your file a Blade Template? It has to end with `.blade.php`

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yes my file adds with `.blade.php`

Comment: I've just tried your code in a clean install of Laravel 4.2 and it works as expected. Check in `C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel-test\app\storage\views\7b9d8c08d036e7d846a7a4ea676e0658` on line 695 to see what's been compiled there.

Comment: @Bogdan Thx for that! At line 695 I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/test_app/')}}load-scripts.js      "></script>
`

Comment: @mrquad In the compiled view you should have `<?php echo URL::asset('assets/test_app/'); ?>` not `{{ URL::asset('assets/test_app/')}}`, which means the view is not being compiled properly. How are you returning the view in your route/controller?

Comment: @Bogdan Please have a look at my update!

Comment: @mrquad I can't seem to replicate the problem. Try creating an isolated test. Create a new view, for example in `site/testview.blade.php` and add this single line `{{ URL::asset('assets/test_app/')}}` to it (no other markup). Then create a route that renders that view. Let me know if that throws an error as well.

Comment: @Bogdan I did this and I basically get the path to my javascript files back. So no error ;(

Comment: @mrquad Now what happens if you copy the 3 lines over into this test view?

Comment: If there's no error in the test view, then it means there's something specifically wrong in the `contract_v02` view. I wish could help more but I would have to ask you to post you're entire view file (and I'm not sure if you can share that, maybe it's part of some project that you can't post publicly).

Comment: @lukasgeiter Actually, the js scripts get loaded properly. I guess I need to add them at a certain place. Where should I put them? At the moment, they are inside the `<baody>-tag`?

Comment: @Bogdan Sorry cannot share it. But having the js in the body tags seems to be the problem. Any recommendations where to put them?

Comment: @mrquad I'd put them in the `<head>`

Comment: @mrquad Altough I don't think thats the real problem. Maybe something else is breaking the view before. But without the full code it's hard to say more

Comment: @mrquad where the tags are placed has nothing to do with that error. I believe there's some other error (maybe bad blade syntax) somewhere in the file that is getting compiled wrong. All I can suggest is to check your syntax thoroughly for any errors in it.